# Ajax call with multiple data

Tags: php, ajax, pagination

I have this ajax call and I need to add multiple data.

```
            function sssssss(page){
                loading_show(); 
              var form2 = document.myform2;
              var dataString1 = $(form2).serialize();                   
                $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "load_data.php",
                    data: "page="+page,
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                        $("#container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                        {
                            loading_hide();
                            $("#container").html(msg);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
```

Now in

```
data: "page="+page, // I want  to add "dataString1"
```

I would like to add **var dataString1.**

Any help?

Comment: What does not work with that? What did you expect, what did it instead? Any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the correct way would be:

```
data: {page: page, dataString1: dataString1},
```

The [type](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) of `data` is either a [String](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#String) or a [PlainObject](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using POST to submit form data. There's different possibilities to achieve what you want, the easiest would be to submit your page as a GET param in the URL and submit your serialized form values as the ajax data parameter, like so:

```
var dataString1 = $(form2).serialize();                   
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "load_data.php?page="+page,
    data: dataString1,
    success: function(...){}
});
```

Comment: this is good but not in my case..